# How to buy shares with Interactive Brokers? Stupid question it seems but is really challenging

Tags: interactive-brokers

I had multiple accounts with different brokers.

I used to just hit the buy button with the amount or quantity I need. Transaction completed in seconds.

With IB I am really confused.

1) Terminology

I am not sure if the concept of buying shares in IB is the same, or it actually refers to Stock CDFs, since the transaction process looks so different.

2) Buy is not buy?

There are so many transaction states. What should I expect after hitting buy button?

3) Price

I hoped I see the price, I hit buy and I get the stock. Is there something I still don't get? If the transaction will be completed after minutes the price will be other than the one I agreed for. In case there are smart algorithms, can I just avoid them and go for the easy buy?

4) Are there video tutorials on this specific topic of buying Stock (not stock CDFs or other engineered investment alternatives)

Thanks, hope you understand my confusion.

Comment: By CDF do you mean CFD (Contract For Difference)?  CFD cannot be traded by retail investors in the US so I doubt that's happening.

Comment: Yes, so I suspect that what Interactive Rockers refers to shares is a different product that what I am expecting.

Comment: IB has several platforms (standalone, web based,) and there is Classic and Mosaic views, let alone country variations. Can you provide a screen  shot of  the quotes from your trading page (bid, ask, last, volume, bid size, ask size or whatever you've chosen to display)? In classic, if you hover the cursor over the symbol, it provides info.  If you double click the symbol, it opens a detailed description page (type of security, exchange, dividend, etc).  You can trade directly or you can use Preview to review the trade. Take a look [HERE](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=14082)